# Invalid JSON with markup of my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have created jquery script that was successfully run on my local machine.but when i uploaded the same script on remote server then jquery script generate error. error is "Invalid Json" and XMLHttpRequest.responseText property show my html page markup in. i have spent 3 days on internet to find the solution but i didn't.   my code is here:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/test2.aspx")%>'

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                        url: pageUrl+ "/ServerSideMethod",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert("1");
                        $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                    },
                       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Failure: " + textStatus + XMLHttpRequest.responseText ); 
                   }

                  })                     
                return false;
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

and my web method is

_

```
Public Shared Function ServerSideMethod() As String

    Return ("Muhammad Aurangzeb")

End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post the json aswell?

Comment: Which Browser do you use? I would suggest you use Firefox and equip it with Firebug to have better debugging options. Posting the firebugoutput would help alot.

Comment: Try running your JSON through JSONLint: http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the json generated by your "/ServerSideMethod". Check is validity with http://jsonlint.com/ to find the problem.
Often an history of quotes ' versus the good use of "

Comment: My JOSN code is  


   <WebMethod()> _

    Public Shared Function ServerSideMethod() As String

        Return ("Muhammad Aurangzeb")

    End Function

Answer (score 0):

If your page method is returning the page's HTML, but your local setup is working correctly, your remote server isn't configured correctly.

If it's ASP.NET 3.5, make sure the remote server's web.config matches your local one.

If it's ASP.NET 2.0, you need to also install the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions.

More information: http://encosia.com/2010/03/08/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/